# Sass Sourcemap wrong lines - webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

It looks like that sass-loader is generating a sourcemap which point out wrong lines.

I am not sure if it is a bug or a bad rule configuration however, after a long few days looking for a answer I was not able to find and solution.

Here a example of what is wrong, it is possible to see on first screenshot my css on line 12 is point out by the source map at line 6.

(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13212208/58823784-e6208380-8610-11e9-9182-a4ff059eff0b.png)

(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13212208/58823790-e7ea4700-8610-11e9-9538-b26ba37270af.png)

Could you please guys help me out to get what could be wrong here?

- Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04
- Node Version: 10.15.3
- NPM Version: 6.9.0
- webpack Version: 4.29.6
- sass-loader Version: 7.1.0

#### Code - webpack - Sass rules

```js
    // Docs SASS files
    {
        test: /[\\/]dev-tools[\\/]docs[\\/].+\.scss$/,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```